# Object Cast after refactoring package

Tags: java, serialization, casting, refactoring

I have run upon an error which i cannot figure out how to solve.
I had a Login class in a package i called jdbc, which did all the database stuff, i have now changed the architecture of my program somewhat and put all of that in my class with the actual GUI for Login view.
I have also renamed the jdbc package to database.

Now in my function that deserializes a file containing the stored user data which i need to explicitly cast to a LoginBean object the compiler now tells me the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: jdbc.LoginBean cannot be cast to database.LoginBean
```

How do i make the compiler cast the right one, 'cause the jdbc.LoginBean doesn't even exist anymore.

EDIT:
A piece of the code (removed alot of code in between 'cause they matter not here) -

```
    import database.LoginBean;

    // INSTANCE VARIABLES ------------------------------------------------------
    private LoginBean bean;

    /**
     * Loads the stored login data from user.dat.
     * @return Returns an ArrayList of Strings containing the retrieved username
     * and password.
     */
    private ArrayList<String> loadLoginData() {
// Load saved data if present
        bean = null;
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fIo = new FileInputStream("user.dat");
            ObjectInputStream oIo = new ObjectInputStream(fIo);

            bean = (LoginBean)oIo.readObject();

            oIo.close();
            fIo.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }

        listData.add(bean.getUsername());
        listData.add(bean.getPassword());
        saveSelected = bean.isSelected();

        return listData;
    }
```

Comment: Also, i really do not understand why this even happens. Can anyone explain what is actually happening here?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project. And check your imports. It's telling you that on that line you still have a `jdbc.LoginBean`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It has been no success though, it is giving me a ClassNotFoundException this time, still at the cast. I have checked the imports before and made sure they were pointed at the right classes. EDIT: Even if i ctrl-click on the LoginBean cast it sends to me to the Class in the correct pacakge, really weird.

Comment: Tried pointing it directly by casting like (database.LoginBean) still gives me ClassNotFoundException cannot find jdbc.LoginBean

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to cast something? What are you trying to cast? You said you got rid of the `jdbc` package which means ... it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: No, i refactored the package name into database. I am casting an Object to a LoginBean object for deserialization. If i revert the package name back to jdbc it works. edit: let me add some code to main post.

Comment: NOW it makes sense. And I see you figured it out :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was tardy enough to forget that of course the file containing object data which i was trying to deserialize still pointed to the package jdbc which did no longer exist after refactoring it. After removing the file it compiles properly again.

Boy, do i feel like an idiot now :-P